# Java FTP upload

Tags: java, sockets, ftp, connection, aruba

I got this issue that is bothering me for a week now,

I'm trying to upload a file xml with ftp using java, nothing too fancy.

After a few web serch i decided to use the ftp4j pack wich, according to the documentation should do the trick.

Point is that this ftp server actually work with Filezilla...

these are a few line of my code:

```
    public void connect() {
    try {


        String[] con = client.connect(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < con.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(con[i]);
        }

        client.login(user, password);

        s = client.getHost();
        System.out.println(s);

        con = client.help();
        for (int i = 0; i < con.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(con[i]);
        }

        client.changeDirectory(sDir);
        s = client.currentDirectory();

        System.setProperty("ftp4j.passiveDataTransfer.useSuggestedAddress", "1");

        client.setPassive(true);

        System.out.println(client.isPassive());

        client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);

        client.upload(file);


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ftpConnector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println(ex.toString());

    }
}
```

well i get this output:

```
*
*                                 
*  Aruba.it                    
#  The Web Hosting Company     
#                                 
#
This is a private system - No anonymous login
ftp.open-eye.it
The following SITE commands are recognized
 CHMOD
 IDLE
 UTIME
Pure-FTPd - http://pureftpd.org/

true
[code=200, message=TYPE is now ASCII]

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

I'm pretty sure the Connection reset is related to the upload command i give with client.upload(file);

all my vars are declared on an upper level.

```
ava.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read0(StreamDecoder.java:126)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:112)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:168)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.NVTASCIIReader.readLine(NVTASCIIReader.java:105)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPCommunicationChannel.read(FTPCommunicationChannel.java:142)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPCommunicationChannel.readFTPReply(FTPCommunicationChannel.java:187)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.openPassiveDataTransferChannel(FTPClient.java:3534)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.openDataTransferChannel(FTPClient.java:3468)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.download(FTPClient.java:3297)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.download(FTPClient.java:3208)
at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.download(FTPClient.java:3073)
```

Thanks for your time,
Francesco.

Comment: Did you try commenting out the System.setProperty("ftp4j.passiveDataTransfer.useSuggestedAddress", "1"); line to see if the client can successfully open a PASV connection to the server using the original control connection address vs. the suggested server address?

Comment: Tbh i did and it did not work. In order to be sure about this i even set the variable at 0 tho it's still the same. Are you aware of any decent API that i may try out?

Comment: Might want to consider using the Apache Commons Net library http://commons.apache.org/net/. That is a solid library that works well.